# C# - Linq - get Index on - Help

Tags: c#, linq, indexing, indexof

could someone help me with the linq statement,

this is what i have so far

```
public class Categories : ObservableCollection<Category>
{ 
    public Categories() { } 

    public int getBoardIndex(int BoardId)
    {
        return (from category in this
                from board in category.CategoryBoards
                where board.BoardId == BoardId
                select IndexOf(board)
                    );
    }
}
```

board is an item in category and when i pass a bordId ( which is not an index ) it must search for that BoardId in all boards in each category and then return the Index Of that board

how do i do it using Linq?

Thank you so much for all your help!!!

Comment: Right now you are selecting from 'this'.  Are you trying to add an extension method to an object?  What is 'this' in this context?

Comment: this is an ObservableCollection of Categories

Comment: public class Categories : ObservableCollection<Category>
{
 public Categories()
 {
 }
}

Comment: Is the index supposed to be the index of the Board in it's own Category, or the index out of all Categories? For instance, Category0 has 3 boards, and Category1 has 2 boards. If we match the second board in the Category1, is the index supposed to be 1, or 4?

Comment: You call `IndexOf(board)` on a collection of Categories. It won't be found, if it even compiles.

Comment: why was my post down graded? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This is a much simpler version of the same thing:

```
public int getBoardIndex(int BoardId)
{
    return (from category in this
            from board in category.CategoryBoards
            where board.BoardId == BoardId
            select category.CategoryBoards.ToList().IndexOf(board)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**Original Version**

To get the index of the first matching Board in its own Category, first find the Category, then get the index of the board:

```
public int getBoardIndex(int BoardId)
{

    var categoryBoard = (from category in this
                         from board in category.CategoryBoards
                         where board.BoardId == BoardId
                         select new {category, board}).FirstOrDefault();
    return categoryBoard.category.CategoryBoards.IndexOf(categoryBoard.board);
}
```

To get the index of the first matching Board in a flattened collection amongst all of the Categories, then @Dan Tao has the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want something like this:

```
public int getBoardIndex(int BoardId)
{
    var potentialBoards = from category in this
                          from board in category.CategoryBoards
                          select board;

    return potentialBoards.ToList().FindIndex(b => b.BoardId == BoardId);
}
```

Comment: I don't see FindIndex for ToList() ?

Comment: @Kathy: `ToList()` should give you a `List<Board>`. `FindIndex` is a method of the `List<T>` class.

Answer (score 0):

So far, you have an IEnumerable, containing the indices of any board IDs that matched.

If you know that there is exactly one board that matches, you can call .Single() and return that single index. If there might or might not be one board that matches, then you can call .ToList() and assign the result to a variable. Then check whether the list has any items and either return the first item or -1 (or throw an exception, or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, without seeing the object class, I can't be sure, but it should be close to this:

```
public static int getBoardIndex(this ObservableCollection<Category> coll, int BoardId)
{
    return coll.IndexOf((
                from category in coll
                from board in category.CategoryBoards
                where board.BoardId == BoardId
                select category).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Comment: `this ObservableCollection<Category>` ?

Comment: you are calling this as an extension method. Over simplified example: var t = new ObservableCollection<Category>();   t.getBoardIndex(5);

Comment: This returns the index of the category, not the board.

Comment: @Dave I think the point is that it won't compile.  Extension methods can only be declared in a static class, and the method itself must be static.  Also even though it's `this` you still need to give the parameter a name other than `this`.

Comment: @Dave extension method first parameter has to have a name. `this ObservableCollection<Category> foo`

Comment: Still won't work because the method isn't static, and we don't know that it's in a static class (and also you'd need `coll.IndexOf`)

Comment: +1 because I didn't know extension methods had to be static.  And thanks for catching my crappy code (I am ready for the weekend)

Comment: hmmmmm i need the index of board not category